# Can't parse String from stdin to floating-point - Rust

Tags: casting, rust, floating-point, type-conversion

When parsing a String type value to a floating-point type value in Rust, everything works fine with
`"let pi: f64 = 3.14".parse().unwrap();`.

However, when parsing a String type value that comes from standard input, even if it's the exact same value, the program panics and throws:

> thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err`
>   value: ParseFloatError { kind: Invalid }', src/libcore/result.rs:999:5
>   note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a
>   backtrace.

I checked the value's type, and it *is* a String, so I don't understand what the error is about, and I haven't been able to find anything related specifically to standard input (stdin) and this issue. Has anyone else come across this? Is there a good way to prevent the panic?

Here is some code to replicate the issue:

```
use std::io::{stdin,stdout,Write};

fn main() {
    let mut s = String::new();

    println!("Give a number ");

    stdin().read_line(&mut s)
        .expect("Did not enter a correct string");

    let user_input: f64 = s.parse().unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", user_input)
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the input have a trailing newline? You may need to strip that out.

Comment: "Is there a good way to prevent the panic?" don't call method that can panic ? `unwrap()` is not a good thing to use in a real program.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As suggested by SCappella the new line needs to be removed.
The following will work:

```rust
let user_input: f64 = s.trim().parse().unwrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

Much thanks to Jeff Muizelaar and SCappella!

SCappella pointed out that there is a newline character causing the type conversion to fail, and Jeff Muizelaar pointed out that adding a trim() method to the String, "s," would remove the newline, resolving the issue.

After realizing that was the issue, I was able to do some more accurate Googling and found [this bit of Rust documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_line). It explains that the read_line() method

> "read[s] all bytes until a newline (the 0xA byte) is reached...Once found, all
>   bytes up to, **and including**, the delimiter (if found) will be
>   appended..."