# Unable to pass string from read_line to Command arg

Tags: rust, command, iwconfig

I have the following rust routine which executes fine:

```
use std::process::Command;
fn main() {
    let out = Command::new("iwconfig")
        .arg("wlan0")
        .output()
        .expect("Failed to execute 'iwconfig'");

    println!("status:\n {}", out.status);
    println!("stdout:\n {}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&out.stdout));
    println!("stderr:\n {}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&out.stderr));
}
```

It simply prints the result of the `iwconfig` command in linux with the `wlan0` adapter as target. 
The output is fine for this program.

My goal enable the user to enter an adapter manually. If I execute the following program and enter `wlan0` manually when prompted:

```
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    let mut adapter_input = String::new();
    println!("{}", "Enter adapter name:");
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut adapter_input).unwrap();

    let out = Command::new("iwconfig")
        .arg(adapter_input)
        .output()
        .expect("Failed to execute 'iwconfig'");

    println!("status:\n {}", out.status);
    println!("stdout:\n {}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&out.stdout));
    println!("stderr:\n {}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&out.stderr));
}
```

I get the following output:

> wlan0 status:  exit code: 237 stdout:   stderr:  wlan0
>       No such device

What am I doing wrong? Why is the adapter found when hardcoded but not found when entered manually?

Comment: There's a newline character in the input buffer. Does this answer your question? [Can't parse String from stdin to floating-point - Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58567077/cant-parse-string-from-stdin-to-floating-point-rust)

Comment: To apply the answer to that question to your problem, try `.arg(adapter_input.trim())`.

Comment: @trentcl This did solve my issue. Please feel free to write an answer, I will accept it.